# Form Size Within Modal

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a form page that opens inside a Modal, but when I open the modal, the form does not appear complete, the modal cuts a part of it, is there any possibility of modal getting the page size?

html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header  bg-warning text-white">
        <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Change, Update Wallet</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe id="iframeModal1" class="embed-responsive-item" src=""></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--end modal -->
```

**-- EDITED**

Solved! I adjusted by putting

```
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: do you have the css or js that's used with the modal?

Comment: no, no have. bootstrap only

Comment: glad you got it solved!

Comment: Yes, on the computer was 100%, but I see that on the phone is still appearing cut

Answer (score 0):

You use `embed-responsive-16by9` (16:9) this only works if your delivered content is not exceeding this ratio.

A possible solution is to add a Listener to wait for your iframe to be loaded:

First remove `embed-responsive-16by9`
Then set the height of your surrounding conainer to your iframes height

```
$('iframeModal1').on('load', function({
  $('.embed-responsive').height($(this).contents().height());
});
```

You may want to set the height again in case the windows gets resized (portait/landscape)
`$(window).on('resize', ... )`

Comment: Thanks but it did not work for me, I believe it is close to achieve, because only the height is a small view of a mobile phone, thus creating a scroll bar